# Best way to push data from http server side to browser client

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, push-notification

What will be the best way to push data from server side to client, while client is a web browser.

My server side is build in java, and client side is on html, js, ajax.

Mode of communication is HTTP protocol.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

WebSockets is the "real" way to do it.
 [WebSockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket)

Java Implementation [Atmosphere](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere)